# I am working on App like Uber , please let me know that in this App we can use Apple Pay & Paypal Payment Gateway

Tags: ios, paypal

I am working on App like Uber , please let me know that in this App we can use Apple Pay & Paypal Payment Gateway. Because in my last Grocery App , Apple rejected my App continuously until I used In App Purchase Payment gateway. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **3.1.5 (a)** **Goods and Services Outside of the App: -** If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of
>   the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to
>   collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card
>   entry.

So please use **Paypal** or other payment gateway instead of **IAP**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But as you're offering something in physical (i.e., taxi service) you better avoid **In App Purchase** as they'll **deduct 30% of your payment**. Since **Apple approved** non Standard (i.e., other payment methods as Apple Pay & Paypal) for **physical services**, you better go with a different one (e.g., paypal). Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the 30% from? Their documentation states ‘no additional fees’ https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started/